# Do we get bounty points if we have reached rep cap for a day?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I answered a question but didn't get bounty points [Only count a download once it's served](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534150/only-count-a-download-once-its-served/7552329#7552329) I had already reached rep cap. Is this a bug or is it by design (its unfair if thats the case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounties aren't tied to accepted answers, and they don't count against the rep limit (see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)).

That question still has an active bounty. You didn't get it, at least yet. The asker already accepted your answer, and he'll likely award you the bounty too, but bounties have a minimum active time of 1 day.

[In 5 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7534150/revisions) from now, he can award it, although he might choose to wait until the bounty period ends (for more exposure).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we/you do. Bounties, and accepted answers aren't counted in your daily cap limit. However, you haven't received any bounty because nobody gave it to you. Bounty is still active

Comment: @agf: Grammatical mistake. "Do we get bounty points if we have reached rep cap for a day?" -> "Yes, we/you do"